# Why am I losing an unspecified amount of Sol when making a transaction?

Tags: sol

I am conducting experiments with buying and selling meme coins using a bot. I attempted to make a purchase with only 0.001 Sol. However, my account was deducted 0.003 Sol. Besides the detailed fees shown in the transaction, I cannot determine why a portion of my Sol is missing. Later, when checking the "Sol Balance Change" section in the transaction history, I found that 0.002 Sol was transferred to an address. Upon inspecting that address, I realized it is a token account with a Sol balance that belongs to me, and I am the owner of that token account. Why does this activity occur, and why is it not displayed in the transaction information? How can I recover the lost Sol? I am concerned about potential losses if I conduct transactions with larger amounts...
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

the 0.002 is the rent of the token account.
This activity occurs because when you are purchasing this token, and since you didn't had a token account for that specific mint. You need to create that token account(will hold balance of that mint).
In order to get this token rent balance back, you need to close your token account. Since i assume you are not a dev you can use the wallet inbuilt features, or there is a known dapp called sol-incinerator wich allows you to close in bulk.

Have a nice day.

Comment: I’d also add that this is a one off - if you don’t close the token account then it’ll be used for that token going forward. So you won’t have that additional cost in future transactions with the same token.